# Get the return elements from the triggered Event in backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I am tirggering an event. which is triggered and executed successfully. Below is the code.

```
 ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
 events: {
  "click":"onClick"
  },
 onClick: function() {
  //trigger a custom event, passing the view as first argument
   Events.trigger('click', this);
  }
});

  ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
       this.listenTo(Events, 'click', this._onClick);

    },
   _onClick:function(itemView) {
      //...
       return x;

     }
    });
```

But I want to return data on the triggered event. In _onClick  I want to return some data.

since we only doEvents.trigger("methodname", parameters). How to get the return data which is x in the above case from _onClick function to OnClick in ItemView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this:

Wrap whatever you need in an object & use it.

```
 ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
 events: {
  "click":"onClick"
  },
 onClick: function() {
  //trigger a custom event, passing the view as first argument
   var dataObj = { 'ItemView': this, 'otherProp': 'other value' };
   Events.trigger('click', dataObj);
  }
});

  ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
       this.listenTo(Events, 'click', obj);

       obj.ItemView._onClick(obj);


    },
   _onClick:function(obj) {
      //...
       return x;

     }
    });
```